# TFS: Msbuild not found on Mac Build agent. Terminal confirms Msbuild is present

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I'm getting an error that Msbuild can't be found on MacOS.

```
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0' from '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/4.5'.

MsBuild.exe does not exist at '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/4.5/msbuild.exe'.

Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono failed with return code: 1
Packages failed to install
```

**Testing**

1. However I was able to find MSBuild installed on my machine:

   ```
   lamont$ msbuild /version
   Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.0.0
   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

   Lamont$ which msbuild
   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/msbuild
   ```

[image]

**Question**

How can I fix this error in the TFS build client?

Answer (score 0):

This was a nuget [bug](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3085) which has since been fixed. You could get a newer version with the fix from https://dist.nuget.org/index.html .